# nginx: [emerg] unexpected ";" in </path/to>/php-fpm.conf:1

Tags: php, nginx

```
Operating system: openSUSE Leap 15.
Type: Guest ( Linux virtual machine ).
```

Nginx had been successfully serving up info.php file until four days ago.  The full text of the error message is as follows:

```
"nginx: [emerg] unexpected ";" in </path/to>/php-fpm.conf:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed."
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire Nginx configuration across all included files.